# how to merge two strings into one by using chartAt() and arrays technique

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

as mentioned in the title, I got an error in each line inside for loop which says (variable expected) and this is my code

```
 String s = "ABC";
    String t = "DEFGH";
    String merge = "";
    // merge should looks like "ADBECFGH"
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < s.length(); i=i+2) {
        merge.charAt(i) = s.charAt(i/2);
        merge.charAt(i+1) = t.charAt(i/2);
    }
    for (; i < t.length()+s.length() ; i++) {
        merge.charAt(i) = t.charAt(i-s.length());
    }
```

am trying to use same technique with arrays which I think its very effective.

Comment: One problem is that `merge` starts as an empty string, so when you try to get the `charAt` any index, it will not be able to and thus throw an error. Note that this algorithm actually shouldn't need you to read anything from `merged`. See where you can get with this advice

Comment: String is immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one, since you are manipulating `Strings` inside a loop, it is better to use `StringBuilder` instead of String.

```
    String s = "ABC";
    String t = "DEFGH";
    StringBuilder merge = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() || i < t.length(); i++) {
        if (i < s.length()) {
            merge.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
        if (i < t.length()) {
            merge.append(t.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(merge.toString());
```

Comment: its really brilliant man, you solved another problem for me. when s length is bigger than t length. I had solution but it was long one. my mind was flying around the same solution of yours but didn't reach it. thanks

Comment: @husseinalbirouti nice to help !

Comment: I have question:  StringBuilder getting characters from s then from t but how  it works with StringBuilder without select the index where the characters going to set in. its like starting from the next index always??

Comment: @husseinalbirouti `StringBuilder`'s `.append()` method take care of that, it appends the string representation of the char which come from `charAt()` to its sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you like take one letter from first string and then from other try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() || i < t.length(); i++) {
    if (i < s.length()) {
        merge += String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
    }
    if (i < t.length()) {
        merge += String.valueOf(t.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

This is condition that let you iterate till longer `String` finish

```
i < s.length() || i < t.length()
```

Answer (score 0):

The method charAt(int index) returns the character at the specified index(IT IS A GETTER NOT A SETTER). You cannot use it as
`merge.charAt(i) = s.charAt(i/2)`

one of the easiest ways to perform such operation is to use string operation such as concatination as shown in the below example

```
 s="abc";
 t="def";
 System.out.print(s.concat(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the .concact() method without using the for loop:

so your code would look like: 
merge = s.concat(t);

Answer (score 0):

```
    CharacterIterator a = new StringCharacterIterator("haaaaallo");
    CharacterIterator b = new StringCharacterIterator("12345");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if(a.getEndIndex() < b.getEndIndex()) { //true -> swap a and b
        CharacterIterator holder = a;
        a = b;
        b = holder;
    }
    while (a.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
        output.append(a.current());
        while (b.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE) {
            output.append(b.current());
            break;
        }
        a.next();
        b.next();
    }
    System.out.println(output.toString()); //h1a2a3a4a5allo
```

To show "the manual way". The used Strings can be any size.

Answer (score 0):

try this : concatenate two string without inbuilt method and without + operator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "ABC";
    String s1 = "DEF";
    String merge = "";
    char[]ch = new char[120];

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        ch[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<s1.length();i++) {
        ch[s.length()+i] = s1.charAt(i);
    }

    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go with @Bartek's answer its simple and easy to remember..
the complicated way to achieve this would be

```
String a = "abcdefgh";
String b = "ijklmnopqrst";
int i = 0;
StringBuilder merge = new StringBuilder();
for (; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++) {
    merge.append(a.charAt(i)).append(b.charAt(i));
}
if (i < a.length())
    merge.append(a.substring(i));
if (i < b.length())
    merge.append(b.substring(i));
```

Only to avoid having if conditions inside the for loop.. (optimal only in case of large strings, strings of vastly different lengths)